# CKEditor align images instead of float

Tags: php, javascript, alignment, ckeditor, css-float

All,

I'm very successfully using CKEditor in my app that allows clients to build and send HTML Emails.  There's just one hitch--CK uses style="float:left" for images, while Outlook refuses to accept that as valid (way to go, Microsoft..)  FCKEditor used to use aligns instead of floats to position images.  Is there a way to hack CKEditor to behave as FCK used to with regards to image alignment?

Posts to CK's forums have been futile.  Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: oops strange mather. do you try to change CKEditor's source code.

Comment: Fatih, yes, trying to figure out where to change it.  The source code is large and convoluted at times.  If I only knew where to start....

Comment: There is a folder name `_source` in ckeditor distribution source. All the original javascript plugins is placed there. You can modified from there ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absent any really spot-on answers, I did my own research.  The only correct way to solve this issue is to update the plugins/image/dialogs/image.js file with the following code that prioritizes html entities over that of CSS.  The solution makes a WYSIWYG editor that's near perfect for Email editor applications, and also the only solution I've found that 100% eliminates the issue of drag-and-drop from Microsoft creating HORRIBLE extra markup.

```
(function(){var imageDialog=function(editor,dialogType){var IMAGE=1,LINK=2,PREVIEW=4,CLEANUP=8,regexGetSize=/^\s*(\d+)((px)|\%)?\s*$/i,regexGetSizeOrEmpty=/(^\s*(\d+)((px)|\%)?\s*$)|^$/i,pxLengthRegex=/^\d+px$/;var onSizeChange=function(){var value=this.getValue(),dialog=this.getDialog(),aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(aMatch){if(aMatch[2]=='%')switchLockRatio(dialog,false);value=aMatch[1]}if(dialog.lockRatio){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){if(this.id=='txtHeight'){if(value&&value!='0')value=Math.round(oImageOriginal.$.width*(value/oImageOriginal.$.height));if(!isNaN(value))dialog.setValueOf('info','txtWidth',value)}else{if(value&&value!='0')value=Math.round(oImageOriginal.$.height*(value/oImageOriginal.$.width));if(!isNaN(value))dialog.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',value)}}}updatePreview(dialog)};var updatePreview=function(dialog){if(!dialog.originalElement||!dialog.preview)return 1;dialog.commitContent(PREVIEW,dialog.preview);return 0};function commitContent(){var args=arguments;var inlineStyleField=this.getContentElement('advanced','txtdlgGenStyle');inlineStyleField&&inlineStyleField.commit.apply(inlineStyleField,args);this.foreach(function(widget){if(widget.commit&&widget.id!='txtdlgGenStyle')widget.commit.apply(widget,args)})}var incommit;function commitInternally(targetFields){if(incommit)return;incommit=1;var dialog=this.getDialog(),element=dialog.imageElement;if(element){this.commit(IMAGE,element);targetFields=[].concat(targetFields);var length=targetFields.length,field;for(var i=0;i<length;i++){field=dialog.getContentElement.apply(dialog,targetFields[i].split(':'));field&&field.setup(IMAGE,element)}}incommit=0}var switchLockRatio=function(dialog,value){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(!oImageOriginal)return null;var ratioButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnLockSizesId);if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){if(value=='check'){var width=dialog.getValueOf('info','txtWidth'),height=dialog.getValueOf('info','txtHeight'),originalRatio=oImageOriginal.$.width*1000/oImageOriginal.$.height,thisRatio=width*1000/height;dialog.lockRatio=false;if(!width&&!height)dialog.lockRatio=true;else if(!isNaN(originalRatio)&&!isNaN(thisRatio)){if(Math.round(originalRatio)==Math.round(thisRatio))dialog.lockRatio=true}}else if(value!=undefined)dialog.lockRatio=value;else dialog.lockRatio=!dialog.lockRatio}else if(value!='check')dialog.lockRatio=false;if(dialog.lockRatio)ratioButton.removeClass('cke_btn_unlocked');else ratioButton.addClass('cke_btn_unlocked');var lang=dialog._.editor.lang.image,label=lang[dialog.lockRatio?'unlockRatio':'lockRatio'];ratioButton.setAttribute('title',label);ratioButton.getFirst().setText(label);return dialog.lockRatio};var resetSize=function(dialog){var oImageOriginal=dialog.originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'){dialog.setValueOf('info','txtWidth',oImageOriginal.$.width);dialog.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',oImageOriginal.$.height)}updatePreview(dialog)};var setupDimension=function(type,element){if(type!=IMAGE)return;function checkDimension(size,defaultValue){var aMatch=size.match(regexGetSize);if(aMatch){if(aMatch[2]=='%'){aMatch[1]+='%';switchLockRatio(dialog,false)}return aMatch[1]}return defaultValue}var dialog=this.getDialog(),value='',dimension=((this.id=='txtWidth')?'width':'height'),size=element.getAttribute(dimension);if(size)value=checkDimension(size,value);value=checkDimension(element.getStyle(dimension),value);this.setValue(value)};var previewPreloader;var onImgLoadEvent=function(){var original=this.originalElement;original.setCustomData('isReady','true');original.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);original.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);original.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');if(!this.dontResetSize)resetSize(this);if(this.firstLoad)CKEDITOR.tools.setTimeout(function(){switchLockRatio(this,'check')},0,this);this.firstLoad=false;this.dontResetSize=false};var onImgLoadErrorEvent=function(){var original=this.originalElement;original.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);original.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);original.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);var noimage=CKEDITOR.getUrl(editor.skinPath+'images/noimage.png');if(this.preview)this.preview.setAttribute('src',noimage);CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');switchLockRatio(this,false)};var numbering=function(id){return id+CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber()},btnLockSizesId=numbering('btnLockSizes'),btnResetSizeId=numbering('btnResetSize'),imagePreviewLoaderId=numbering('ImagePreviewLoader'),imagePreviewBoxId=numbering('ImagePreviewBox'),previewLinkId=numbering('previewLink'),previewImageId=numbering('previewImage');return{title:(dialogType=='image')?editor.lang.image.title:editor.lang.image.titleButton,minWidth:420,minHeight:310,onShow:function(){this.imageElement=false;this.linkElement=false;this.imageEditMode=false;this.linkEditMode=false;this.lockRatio=true;this.dontResetSize=false;this.firstLoad=true;this.addLink=false;var editor=this.getParentEditor(),sel=this.getParentEditor().getSelection(),element=sel.getSelectedElement(),link=element&&element.getAscendant('a');CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId).setStyle('display','none');previewPreloader=new CKEDITOR.dom.element('img',editor.document);this.preview=CKEDITOR.document.getById(previewImageId);this.originalElement=editor.document.createElement('img');this.originalElement.setAttribute('alt','');this.originalElement.setCustomData('isReady','false');if(link){this.linkElement=link;this.linkEditMode=true;var linkChildren=link.getChildren();if(linkChildren.count()==1){var childTagName=linkChildren.getItem(0).getName();if(childTagName=='img'||childTagName=='input'){this.imageElement=linkChildren.getItem(0);if(this.imageElement.getName()=='img')this.imageEditMode='img';else if(this.imageElement.getName()=='input')this.imageEditMode='input'}}if(dialogType=='image')this.setupContent(LINK,link)}if(element&&element.getName()=='img'&&!element.getAttribute('_cke_realelement')||element&&element.getName()=='input'&&element.getAttribute('type')=='image'){this.imageEditMode=element.getName();this.imageElement=element}if(this.imageEditMode){this.cleanImageElement=this.imageElement;this.imageElement=this.cleanImageElement.clone(true,true);this.setupContent(IMAGE,this.imageElement);switchLockRatio(this,true)}else this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');if(!CKEDITOR.tools.trim(this.getValueOf('info','txtUrl'))){this.preview.removeAttribute('src');this.preview.setStyle('display','none')}},onOk:function(){if(this.imageEditMode){var imgTagName=this.imageEditMode;if(dialogType=='image'&&imgTagName=='input'&&confirm(editor.lang.image.button2Img)){imgTagName='img';this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');this.imageElement.setAttribute('alt','');editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else if(dialogType!='image'&&imgTagName=='img'&&confirm(editor.lang.image.img2Button)){imgTagName='input';this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('input');this.imageElement.setAttributes({type:'image',alt:''});editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else{this.imageElement=this.cleanImageElement;delete this.cleanImageElement}}else{if(dialogType=='image')this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('img');else{this.imageElement=editor.document.createElement('input');this.imageElement.setAttribute('type','image')}this.imageElement.setAttribute('alt','')}if(!this.linkEditMode)this.linkElement=editor.document.createElement('a');this.commitContent(IMAGE,this.imageElement);this.commitContent(LINK,this.linkElement);if(!this.imageElement.getAttribute('style'))this.imageElement.removeAttribute('style');if(!this.imageEditMode){if(this.addLink){if(!this.linkEditMode){editor.insertElement(this.linkElement);this.linkElement.append(this.imageElement,false)}else editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}else{if(!this.linkEditMode&&this.addLink){editor.insertElement(this.linkElement);this.imageElement.appendTo(this.linkElement)}else if(this.linkEditMode&&!this.addLink){editor.getSelection().selectElement(this.linkElement);editor.insertElement(this.imageElement)}}},onLoad:function(){if(dialogType!='image')this.hidePage('Link');var doc=this._.element.getDocument();this.addFocusable(doc.getById(btnResetSizeId),5);this.addFocusable(doc.getById(btnLockSizesId),5);this.commitContent=commitContent},onHide:function(){if(this.preview)this.commitContent(CLEANUP,this.preview);if(this.originalElement){this.originalElement.removeListener('load',onImgLoadEvent);this.originalElement.removeListener('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent);this.originalElement.removeListener('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent);this.originalElement.remove();this.originalElement=false}delete this.imageElement},contents:[{id:'info',label:editor.lang.image.infoTab,accessKey:'I',elements:[{type:'vbox',padding:0,children:[{type:'hbox',widths:['280px','110px'],align:'right',children:[{id:'txtUrl',type:'text',label:editor.lang.common.url,required:true,onChange:function(){var dialog=this.getDialog(),newUrl=this.getValue();if(newUrl.length>0){dialog=this.getDialog();var original=dialog.originalElement;dialog.preview.removeStyle('display');original.setCustomData('isReady','false');var loader=CKEDITOR.document.getById(imagePreviewLoaderId);if(loader)loader.setStyle('display','');original.on('load',onImgLoadEvent,dialog);original.on('error',onImgLoadErrorEvent,dialog);original.on('abort',onImgLoadErrorEvent,dialog);original.setAttribute('src',newUrl);previewPreloader.setAttribute('src',newUrl);dialog.preview.setAttribute('src',previewPreloader.$.src);updatePreview(dialog)}else if(dialog.preview){dialog.preview.removeAttribute('src');dialog.preview.setStyle('display','none')}},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var url=element.getAttribute('_cke_saved_src')||element.getAttribute('src');var field=this;this.getDialog().dontResetSize=true;field.setValue(url);field.setInitValue();field.focus()}},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE&&(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())){element.setAttribute('_cke_saved_src',decodeURI(this.getValue()));element.setAttribute('src',decodeURI(this.getValue()))}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.setAttribute('src','');element.removeAttribute('src')}},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty(editor.lang.image.urlMissing)},{type:'button',id:'browse',style:'display:inline-block;margin-top:10px;',align:'center',label:editor.lang.common.browseServer,hidden:true,filebrowser:'info:txtUrl'}]}]},{id:'txtAlt',type:'text',label:editor.lang.image.alt,accessKey:'A','default':'',onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('alt'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('alt',this.getValue())}else if(type==PREVIEW){element.setAttribute('alt',this.getValue())}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('alt')}}},{type:'hbox',widths:['140px','240px'],children:[{type:'vbox',padding:10,children:[{type:'hbox',widths:['70%','30%'],children:[{type:'vbox',padding:1,children:[{type:'text',width:'40px',id:'txtWidth',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.width,onKeyUp:onSizeChange,onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:function(){var aMatch=this.getValue().match(regexGetSizeOrEmpty);if(!aMatch)alert(editor.lang.image.validateWidth);return!!aMatch},setup:setupDimension,commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE){if(value)element.setAttribute('width',value);else if(!value&&this.isChanged())element.removeStyle('width');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('width')}else if(type==PREVIEW){var aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(!aMatch){var oImageOriginal=this.getDialog().originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true')element.setStyle('width',oImageOriginal.$.width+'px')}else element.setStyle('width',value+'px')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('width');element.removeStyle('width')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtHeight',width:'40px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.height,onKeyUp:onSizeChange,onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:function(){var aMatch=this.getValue().match(regexGetSizeOrEmpty);if(!aMatch)alert(editor.lang.image.validateHeight);return!!aMatch},setup:setupDimension,commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE){if(value)element.setAttribute('height',value);else if(!value&&this.isChanged())element.removeStyle('height');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('height')}else if(type==PREVIEW){var aMatch=value.match(regexGetSize);if(!aMatch){var oImageOriginal=this.getDialog().originalElement;if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true')element.setStyle('height',oImageOriginal.$.height+'px')}else element.setStyle('height',value+'px')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('height');element.removeStyle('height')}}}]},{type:'html',style:'margin-top:10px;width:40px;height:40px;',onLoad:function(){var resetButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnResetSizeId),ratioButton=CKEDITOR.document.getById(btnLockSizesId);if(resetButton){resetButton.on('click',function(evt){resetSize(this);evt.data.preventDefault()},this.getDialog());resetButton.on('mouseover',function(){this.addClass('cke_btn_over')},resetButton);resetButton.on('mouseout',function(){this.removeClass('cke_btn_over')},resetButton)}if(ratioButton){ratioButton.on('click',function(evt){var locked=switchLockRatio(this),oImageOriginal=this.originalElement,width=this.getValueOf('info','txtWidth');if(oImageOriginal.getCustomData('isReady')=='true'&&width){var height=oImageOriginal.$.height/oImageOriginal.$.width*width;if(!isNaN(height)){this.setValueOf('info','txtHeight',Math.round(height));updatePreview(this)}}evt.data.preventDefault()},this.getDialog());ratioButton.on('mouseover',function(){this.addClass('cke_btn_over')},ratioButton);ratioButton.on('mouseout',function(){this.removeClass('cke_btn_over')},ratioButton)}},html:'<div>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" title="'+editor.lang.image.unlockRatio+'" class="cke_btn_locked" id="'+btnLockSizesId+'" role="button"><span class="cke_label">'+editor.lang.image.unlockRatio+'</span></a>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" title="'+editor.lang.image.resetSize+'" class="cke_btn_reset" id="'+btnResetSizeId+'" role="button"><span class="cke_label">'+editor.lang.image.resetSize+'</span></a>'+'</div>'}]},{type:'vbox',padding:1,children:[{type:'text',id:'txtBorder',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.border,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateBorder),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,borderStyle=element.getStyle('border-width');borderStyle=borderStyle&&borderStyle.match(/^(\d+px)(?: \1 \1 \1)?$/);value=borderStyle&&parseInt(borderStyle[1],10);isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('border'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('border-width',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('border-style','solid')}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('border-width');element.removeStyle('border-style');element.removeStyle('border-color')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('border')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('border');element.removeStyle('border-width');element.removeStyle('border-style');element.removeStyle('border-color')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtHSpace',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.hSpace,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateHSpace),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,marginLeftPx,marginRightPx,marginLeftStyle=element.getStyle('margin-left'),marginRightStyle=element.getStyle('margin-right');marginLeftStyle=marginLeftStyle&&marginLeftStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginRightStyle=marginRightStyle&&marginRightStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginLeftPx=parseInt(marginLeftStyle,10);marginRightPx=parseInt(marginRightStyle,10);value=(marginLeftPx==marginRightPx)&&marginLeftPx;isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('hspace'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('margin-left',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('margin-right',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value))}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('margin-left');element.removeStyle('margin-right')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('hspace')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('hspace');element.removeStyle('margin-left');element.removeStyle('margin-right')}}},{type:'text',id:'txtVSpace',width:'60px',labelLayout:'horizontal',label:editor.lang.image.vSpace,'default':'',onKeyUp:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},validate:CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer(editor.lang.image.validateVSpace),setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value,marginTopPx,marginBottomPx,marginTopStyle=element.getStyle('margin-top'),marginBottomStyle=element.getStyle('margin-bottom');marginTopStyle=marginTopStyle&&marginTopStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginBottomStyle=marginBottomStyle&&marginBottomStyle.match(pxLengthRegex);marginTopPx=parseInt(marginTopStyle,10);marginBottomPx=parseInt(marginBottomStyle,10);value=(marginTopPx==marginBottomPx)&&marginTopPx;isNaN(parseInt(value,10))&&(value=element.getAttribute('vspace'));this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=parseInt(this.getValue(),10);if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(!isNaN(value)){element.setStyle('margin-top',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value));element.setStyle('margin-bottom',CKEDITOR.tools.cssLength(value))}else if(!value&&this.isChanged()){element.removeStyle('margin-top');element.removeStyle('margin-bottom')}if(!internalCommit&&type==IMAGE)element.removeAttribute('vspace')}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('vspace');element.removeStyle('margin-top');element.removeStyle('margin-bottom')}}},{id:'cmbAlign',type:'select',labelLayout:'horizontal',widths:['35%','65%'],style:'width:90px',label:editor.lang.image.align,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.image.alignLeft,'left'],[editor.lang.image.alignRight,'right']],onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog());commitInternally.call(this,'advanced:txtdlgGenStyle')},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var value=element.getStyle('float');switch(value){case'inherit':case'none':value=''}!value&&(value=(element.getAttribute('align')||'').toLowerCase());this.setValue(value)}},commit:function(type,element,internalCommit){var value=this.getValue();if(type==IMAGE||type==PREVIEW){if(value)element.setAttribute('align',value);else element.removeAttribute('align');!internalCommit&&element.removeStyle('float')}else if(type==CLEANUP)element.removeAttribute('align')}}]}]},{type:'vbox',height:'250px',children:[{type:'html',style:'width:95%;',html:'<div>'+CKEDITOR.tools.htmlEncode(editor.lang.common.preview)+'<br>'+'<div id="'+imagePreviewLoaderId+'" class="ImagePreviewLoader" style="display:none"><div class="loading">&nbsp;</div></div>'+'<div id="'+imagePreviewBoxId+'" class="ImagePreviewBox"><table><tr><td>'+'<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" onclick="return false;" id="'+previewLinkId+'">'+'<img id="'+previewImageId+'" alt="" /></a>'+(editor.config.image_previewText||'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. '+'Maecenas feugiat consequat diam. Maecenas metus. Vivamus diam purus, cursus a, commodo non, facilisis vitae, '+'nulla. Aenean dictum lacinia tortor. Nunc iaculis, nibh non iaculis aliquam, orci felis euismod neque, sed ornare massa mauris sed velit. Nulla pretium mi et risus. Fusce mi pede, tempor id, cursus ac, ullamcorper nec, enim. Sed tortor. Curabitur molestie. Duis velit augue, condimentum at, ultrices a, luctus ut, orci. Donec pellentesque egestas eros. Integer cursus, augue in cursus faucibus, eros pede bibendum sem, in tempus tellus justo quis ligula. Etiam eget tortor. Vestibulum rutrum, est ut placerat elementum, lectus nisl aliquam velit, tempor aliquam eros nunc nonummy metus. In eros metus, gravida a, gravida sed, lobortis id, turpis. Ut ultrices, ipsum at venenatis fringilla, sem nulla lacinia tellus, eget aliquet turpis mauris non enim. Nam turpis. Suspendisse lacinia. Curabitur ac tortor ut ipsum egestas elementum. Nunc imperdiet gravida mauris.')+'</td></tr></table></div></div>'}]}]}]},{id:'Link',label:editor.lang.link.title,padding:0,elements:[{id:'txtUrl',type:'text',label:editor.lang.common.url,style:'width: 100%','default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){var href=element.getAttribute('_cke_saved_href');if(!href)href=element.getAttribute('href');this.setValue(href)}},commit:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged()){element.setAttribute('_cke_saved_href',decodeURI(this.getValue()));element.setAttribute('href','javascript:void(0)/*'+CKEDITOR.tools.getNextNumber()+'*/');if(this.getValue()||!editor.config.image_removeLinkByEmptyURL)this.getDialog().addLink=true}}}},{type:'button',id:'browse',filebrowser:{action:'Browse',target:'Link:txtUrl',url:editor.config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl||editor.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl},style:'float:right',hidden:true,label:editor.lang.common.browseServer},{id:'cmbTarget',type:'select',label:editor.lang.common.target,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.common.targetNew,'_blank'],[editor.lang.common.targetTop,'_top'],[editor.lang.common.targetSelf,'_self'],[editor.lang.common.targetParent,'_parent']],setup:function(type,element){if(type==LINK)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('target'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==LINK){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('target',this.getValue())}}}]},{id:'Upload',hidden:true,filebrowser:'uploadButton',label:editor.lang.image.upload,elements:[{type:'file',id:'upload',label:editor.lang.image.btnUpload,style:'height:40px',size:38},{type:'fileButton',id:'uploadButton',filebrowser:'info:txtUrl',label:editor.lang.image.btnUpload,'for':['Upload','upload']}]},{id:'advanced',label:editor.lang.common.advancedTab,elements:[{type:'hbox',widths:['50%','25%','25%'],children:[{type:'text',id:'linkId',label:editor.lang.common.id,setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('id'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('id',this.getValue())}}},{id:'cmbLangDir',type:'select',style:'width : 100px;',label:editor.lang.common.langDir,'default':'',items:[[editor.lang.common.notSet,''],[editor.lang.common.langDirLtr,'ltr'],[editor.lang.common.langDirRtl,'rtl']],setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('dir'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('dir',this.getValue())}}},{type:'text',id:'txtLangCode',label:editor.lang.common.langCode,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('lang'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('lang',this.getValue())}}}]},{type:'text',id:'txtGenLongDescr',label:editor.lang.common.longDescr,setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('longDesc'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('longDesc',this.getValue())}}},{type:'hbox',widths:['50%','50%'],children:[{type:'text',id:'txtGenClass',label:editor.lang.common.cssClass,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('class'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('class',this.getValue())}}},{type:'text',id:'txtGenTitle',label:editor.lang.common.advisoryTitle,'default':'',onChange:function(){updatePreview(this.getDialog())},setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE)this.setValue(element.getAttribute('title'))},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){if(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())element.setAttribute('title',this.getValue())}else if(type==PREVIEW){element.setAttribute('title',this.getValue())}else if(type==CLEANUP){element.removeAttribute('title')}}}]},{type:'text',id:'txtdlgGenStyle',label:editor.lang.common.cssStyle,'default':'',setup:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE){var genStyle=element.getAttribute('style');if(!genStyle&&element.$.style.cssText)genStyle=element.$.style.cssText;this.setValue(genStyle);var height=element.$.style.height,width=element.$.style.width,aMatchH=(height?height:'').match(regexGetSize),aMatchW=(width?width:'').match(regexGetSize);this.attributesInStyle={height:!!aMatchH,width:!!aMatchW}}},onChange:function(){commitInternally.call(this,['info:cmbFloat','info:cmbAlign','info:txtVSpace','info:txtHSpace','info:txtBorder','info:txtWidth','info:txtHeight']);updatePreview(this)},commit:function(type,element){if(type==IMAGE&&(this.getValue()||this.isChanged())){element.setAttribute('style',this.getValue())}}}]}]}};CKEDITOR.dialog.add('image',function(editor){return imageDialog(editor,'image')});CKEDITOR.dialog.add('imagebutton',function(editor){return imageDialog(editor,'imagebutton')})})();
```

Comment: Could you tell me what you did to make that happen, is it a one lin=e change in the source code???

Comment: I tried using it but (I don't know why) It does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296769/use-of-classes-for-alignement-ckeditor

Comment: this is working but select drop down for alignment does not have text to show 'Left' and 'Right', how to make that work?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative... I found that did the width/height just changed to add the align as well.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    // Ends self closing tags the HTML4 way, like <br>.
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
        {
            elements:
            {
                $: function (element) {
                    // Output dimensions of images as width and height
                    if (element.name == 'img') {
                        var style = element.attributes.style;

                        if (style) {
                            // Get the width from the style.
                            var match = /(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style),
                                width = match && match[1];

                            // Get the height from the style.
                            match = /(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec(style);
                            var height = match && match[1];

                            // Get the align from the style

                            var match = /(?:^|\s)float\s*:\s*(left|right)/i.exec(style),
                            align = match && match[1];

                            if (width) {
                                element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)width\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                                element.attributes.width = width;
                            }

                            if (height) {
                                element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)height\s*:\s*(\d+)px;?/i, '');
                                element.attributes.height = height;
                            }

                            if (align) {
                                element.attributes.style = element.attributes.style.replace(/(?:^|\s)float\s*:\s*(left|right);?/i, '');
                                element.attributes.align = align;
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    if (!element.attributes.style)
                        delete element.attributes.style;

                    return element;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Great, worked for me! Better than changing the source as well as I need CKeditor both for emails and publishing.

Comment: Same for me!  Needed for both emails and publishing, this code works perfectly for my case.  Thanks for saving me the time.

Comment: where/how did you implement this? I tried to create a custom plugin with just this code, but it didn't work (throws errors related to the icon).

Comment: thanks for that, at least it pointed me to the direction of where I'm able to influence the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than edit the ckeditor code, I add a custom plugin to override default behaviours. In this case it will modify the ckeditor image dialog definition by changing the commit function on the align select box.

For help writing a custom plugin: http://www.voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development/

This is from my plugin.js for a custom 'ckoverride' plugin.

```
(function()
{
    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
    {
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event
        // data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        if ( dialogName == 'image' )
        {
            // Get a reference to the "Info" (main) tab.
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
            // Get a reference to the align combo box.
            var align = infoTab.get('cmbAlign');

            // Override the commit function.
            // Changes the image alignment to use the align attribute, not floats.
            align.commit = function( type, element, internalCommit )
            {
                var IMAGE = 1,
                    LINK = 2,
                    PREVIEW = 4,
                    CLEANUP = 8; // constants from image.js
                var value = this.getValue();
                if ( type == IMAGE || type == PREVIEW )
                {
                    if ( value )
                        element.setAttribute( 'align', value );
                    else
                        element.removeAttribute( 'align' );
                }
                else if ( type == CLEANUP )
                    element.removeAttribute( 'align' );
            };
        }
    }
})();

// custom plugin, doesn't actually do anything other than override the default plugins.
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('ckoverride',{
        init:function(e){},
        requires:[]
});
```

Comment: I like your solution however when I tried to add it I got an error "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"  I created a folder named ckoverride with the plugin.js file you pasted above and I adjusted my editor config line to "config.extraPlugins = 'atd-ckeditor,ckoverride';"  thoughts?  @sorohan - thank you for your help

Comment: best answer, it help me.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be helpful but I want to point a way for you. You can easily add new buttons and actions to CKEditors and can configure it's toolbars menu.

here is an example that shows how to implement your own tool for CKEditor.

```
(function(){  
    b='syrinxImage';  
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b,{  
        init:function(c){  
            c.addCommand(b,a);  
            c.ui.addButton('SyrinxImage',{  
            label:'Insert Image',   
            icon: this.path + 'toolBarButton.png',  
            command: b  
        });  
    }  
})();
```

when you done with your own tool you can set or modify CKEditor's toolbar like this

```
[  
    ['Source','-','Templates'],  
    ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],  
    ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],  
    ['Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField'],  
    '/',  
    ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],  
    ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],  
    ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],  
    ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],  
    ['SyrinxImage','SyrinxCode','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'],  
    '/',  
    ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],  
    ['TextColor','BGColor'],  
    ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About']  
]
```

please check the following link for more detailed information.

[first code](http://syrinx.ph/articles/CkEditorPluginGuide.aspx)
[CKEditor JavaScript API](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/)
[Main page of Documentation for CKEditor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide)

I hope, I can be helpful with these.

Answer (score 0):

I am using small jquery code to fix this before saving content:

```
ck_editor_content.find("img").each( function(){
    var img_algn = $(this).css('float');
    $(this).attr('align', img_algn);
});
```